# How do I properly recreate POST request in Python

Tags: python, python-requests

Im pretty new to Python Requests so bear with me. Im trying to POST a requests with the following data

```
data = {
"form_uuid": "taGE9xyeDAYWQw_MyeQvIw",
"formResponse": {"First Name (As per IC/ID)": "nancy",
             "Last Name (As per IC/ID)":"thomas",
             "E-mail":"nancythomas998@gmail.com",
             "Size Selection (US)":"8.5"},
"confirmationMail": "nancythomas998@gmail.com",
"is_pro": "true"
}

enter_raffle = requests.post(URL,data=data)
```

However, because of the dictionary within the dictionary itself, I cant seem to properly recreate the request. If it helps, this is what the form data looks like on the chrome network panel
[formdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbDop.png)

I observed that the request headers' content type was "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" too if that helps

Comment: By recreating the request I assume you mean recreating the form input you show in your screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

The `formResponse` value appears to be JSON. You could try

```
import json


response = {
    "First Name (As per IC/ID)": "nancy",
    "Last Name (As per IC/ID)":"thomas",
    "E-mail":"nancythomas998@gmail.com",
    "Size Selection (US)":"8.5"
}

data = {
    "form_uuid": "taGE9xyeDAYWQw_MyeQvIw",
    "formResponse": json.dumps(response),
    "confirmationMail": "nancythomas998@gmail.com",
    "is_pro": "true"
}

enter_raffle = requests.post(URL,data=data)
```

Comment: damn. I spent hours trying to figure this out since I'm new but you made it look so simple. Thank you so much! Its so relieving to have my script work right now at 3am in the morning. Cheers!